# How to remove an item from a table?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, quick.db

How to add a counter to items in a quick.db table?

```
db.set('myItems', ['Blue', 'red'])
const content = db.get('myItems')
channel.send(content)
```

I get the output as:

```
Blue
Black
Red
```

I expect the output to be like this:

```
1 Blue
2 Black
3 Red
```

How to make the output appear with numbers? P.S Not adding them manually, lol.

Comment: Why did you completely change your question? If you have a new issue please post another question

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) along with [Array#join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

*This Is Assuming* `content` *Returns an Array*

```
db.push('myItems', `Blue`, `Black`, `Red`)

const content = db.get('myItems')
const contentList = content.map((item, i) => `${i} ${item}`).join('\n')

channel.send(contentList)
// 0 Blue
// 1 Black
// 2 Red
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the code but i suggest looping through the array and then doing something like: `channel.send(numberLooped + content)`